# How to export only few collections, not all, from a mongo database?

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

I need to export few collections from mongo database, not all collections.

I know how to export the entire database using command line mongoexport, but I need only few collections

How do I do it?

Comment: First, get the list of collections - by querying in the mongo shell. Use *IX and Win operating system command-line for-loop to iterate the collections and export one for each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You can export a few collections in a database. First, find the list of collections you want to export.

From `mongo` shell you can get list of all collections in the current database using the command: `db.getCollectionNames()`. You figure the collections you want to export from this list.

Suppose you want to export two collections, "movies" and "books" within the `test` database.

For **Windows**, a batch file like this will do the export. E.g.,:

*mongo_exp.bat:*

```
for %%coll IN ("movies","books") DO mongoexport --db=test --collection=%%coll --out=%%coll.json
```

When you run this batch file from the Windows command-prompt it will export two collections to two JSON files: `movies.json` and `books.json`.

For **UNIX** like OS, a bash script like this will do the export. For example: *mongo_exp.sh*:

```
#!/bin/sh
declare -a colls=("movies" "books")
for coll in ${colls[@]}
do
    mongoexport --db=test --collection=$coll --out=$coll.json
done
```

In UNIX environment, make sure the script has execute permission before you run it.